# definition of "weak convergence in $L^1$"

Tags: probability, analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory, weak-convergence

I have encountered two definitions of weak convergence in $L^1$:

1) $X_n\rightarrow X$ weakly in $L_1$ iff $\mathrm{E}(X_n\mathrm{1}_A)\rightarrow \mathrm{E}(X\mathrm{1}_A)$ for every measurable set $A$.

2) $X_n\rightarrow X$ weakly in $L_1$ iff $\mathrm{E}(X_n f)\rightarrow \mathrm{E}(X\mathrm{1}f)$ for every (essentially) bounded measurable function $f$.

my question: are 1) and 2) equivalent?

I see that 2) implies 1) (indicators are bounded), but I have difficulties establishing that 1) implies 2). I tried approximating $f$ by simple functions $f_m$, say, assuming $X_n,X$ are nonnegative for simplicity; the problem: I cannot justify the interchange in the order of taking the limits (first with $n$, and then with $m$). any ideas? I would appreciate any sort of help. many thanks!

Comment: In 1), shouldn't you require also that $\lVert X_n\rVert_1$ is uniformly bounded?

Comment: @Guiseppe: thanks for your comment. Def. 1) is from Hall and Heyde's book on martingale limit theory. I double-checked, they do not assume uniform boundedness. how would uniform boundedness help? thanks!

Comment: With uniform boundedness you can prove that $1)\Rightarrow 2)$ by using the fact that the space of simple functions (which are finite linear combinations of indicator functions) is dense in $L^\infty(\Omega)$. To do that you can do a $3\epsilon$ argument. Without this assumption I think that the result is false.

Comment: ok, I will try to formalize that. thanks!

Comment: @Guiseppe: thanks for your hint again - I managed to write down the argument (under the assumption that $\norm{X_n}_1$ is uniformly bounded).

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro It turns out that boundedness in $L^1$ is contained in the assumption (1).

Comment: @DavideGiraudo: You are right, I have checked. Assumption (1) implies equi-integrability of the sequence $X_n$. As a side note, I would like to remark that this can be proved directly, without appealing to Vitali-Hahn-Saks theorem or Baire category theorem. However, it is a rather long and tedious exercise (it was given during a course in measure theory I attended, that's why I know).

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Maybe you could write an answer with the main steps of the exercise. I would like to see the involved arguments (I found Baire's one quite "natural").

Comment: @DavideGiraudo: The task is to take a sequence $f_j\in L^1(\Omega)$ such that $$\int_A f_j\, d\mu\to 0,\quad \forall A\in \mathcal{F},$$assume by contradiction that it is not equi-integrable and use this to construct a subsequence $f_{j(k)}$ and a measurable set $A$ such that $$\int_A f_{j(k)}\, d\mu \ge c > 0.$$This is a bit tedious but can be done more or less explicitly. Right now I am a bit busy so I prefer not to write down details here, but if you are interested you may look at [this sheet](https://app.box.com/s/qj1imk2voqo52qjjpei2), Exercise 10, Claim 3, pag. 17.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Vitali-Hahn-Saks theorem or Baire category theorem with $\mathcal F$ endowed with the metric $\rho(A,B)=\mu(A\Delta B)$, we can show for each $\varepsilon>0$, there is $\delta>0$ such that if $\mu(A)\lt \delta$ then $|\mathbb E[X_n\chi_A]|\lt \varepsilon$. Taking $A':=A\cap \{X_n\leqslant 0\}$ and $A'':=A\cap \{X_n\gt 0\}$, we can see that $\mathbb E[|X_n|\chi_A]\lt\varepsilon$ whenever $\mu(A)\lt\delta$. Indeed, for a fixed $\varepsilon\gt 0$, we define $$F_N:=\bigcap_{n\geqslant N}\left\{A\in\mathcal F,\left|\mathbb E\left[X_n\chi_A\right]\right|\leqslant\varepsilon\right\}.$$
Each $F_N$ is closed and $\bigcup_NF_N=\mathcal F$, hence by Baire's theorem, there is $N_0$, $r_0$ and $A_0\in\mathcal F$ such that $B_\rho(A_0,r_0)\subset F_{N_0}$. Let $B$ such that $\mu(B)\lt r_0$. Since $\mu(A_0\Delta (A_0\cup B))\lt r_0$, $\mu(A_0\Delta (A_0\cap B^c))\lt r_0$ and 
$$\int_B X_n\mathrm d\mu=\int_{A_0\cup B}X_n\mathrm d\mu-\int_{A_0\cap B^c}X_n\mathrm d\mu,$$
we have $\left|\int_B X_n\mathrm d\mu\right|\leqslant 2\varepsilon$ whenever $n\geqslant N_0$ and $\mu(B)\lt r_0$.

Now we use Theorem 1.12.9 in Bogachev, *Measure theory*, volume 1:

> Let $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mu)$ be a measure space with a finite non-negative measure. Then for each $\delta>0$, we can find an integer $N$ and a finite partition of $\Omega$, $\{S_1,\dots,S_N\}$ such that for each $i$, either $\mu(S_i)\leqslant \delta$ or $S_i$ is an atom of measure $>\delta$.

So take $\varepsilon:=1$, the associated $\delta$, and notice that there are only finitely many atoms of measure $\gt \delta$. On each of these atoms, $X_n$ is constant.

Comment: excellent, many thanks!

Comment: Theorem 4 assumes that the sequence is bounded in L_1 (or am I misreading something) - so that is no good for my purpose here (the Theorem yields UI as a result of boundedness in L_1 + the additional convergence of the integrals). but you can use a version of Vitali-Hahn-Saks to establish UI.

Comment: @s_2 You are right, I should have red it more carefully. I revised my answer. I will add details on the application of Baire's theorem.

Comment: Now I've added details. I realize that what I show is exactly what Neveu's book give (and Hall and Heyde refer to this one).

Comment: great (and very detailed) answer! thanks for all your efforts, I really appreciate it!