# A problem on absolute continuity of measures.

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $(X, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ is a finite measure space, $\{\nu_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of finite measures on $\mathcal{F}$ s.t. $\nu_n \ll \mu$  for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\nu_n(E)=:\nu(E)<\infty$ for all $E\in\mathcal{F}$. I need to show that

$$\lim_{\mu(E)\to 0}\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\nu_n(E)=0.$$

Initially I was proceeding by contradiction, but I found a problem in my solution. So now, I have no idea how to proceed.

Any hints/comments will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Could you post your attempt? Maybe we will be able to fix the potential problem in your solution.

Answer (score 0):

We can assume that $(X,\mathcal F,\mu)$ is a probability space. By Radon-Nikodym's theorem, let $X_n$ be positive functions such that $\nu_n(E):=\int_E X_n(\omega)\mathrm d\mu(\omega)$ for each $E\in\mathcal F$. Notice that Vitali-Hahn-Saks theorems implies that $\nu$ is a positive measure, and by the assumptions, absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$. There thus exists $X$ such that $\nu(E):=\int_E X(\omega)\mathrm d\mu(\omega)$ for each $E\in\mathcal F$. Since for each $E\in\mathcal F$, $\mathbb E_\mu[X_n\chi_E]\to\mathbb E_\mu[X\chi_E]$, we conclude [by this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/521546/definition-of-weak-convergence-in-l1).