# Can we say that : $f_\infty=\beta_\infty$ $a.e$?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $(E,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a finite measure space.

Let $\{f_n\}\subset L_{\mathbb{R}}^{1}$, $\{\beta_k\}\subset  L_{\mathbb{R}}^{1}$ and $\beta_\infty, f_\infty\in  L_{\mathbb{R}}^{1}$, such that:
$$
f_n\overset{\sigma(L_{\mathbb{R}}^{1},L_{\mathbb{R}}^{\infty})}{\longrightarrow}f_{\infty}
\qquad
\text{and}
\qquad
 f_n1_{[|f_n|\leq k]}\overset{\sigma(L_{\mathbb{R}}^{1},L_{\mathbb{R}}^{\infty})}{\longrightarrow}  \beta_k \qquad \forall k\geq 1.
$$
we suppose that:
$$
\beta_k \underset{k}{\rightarrow} \beta_\infty~~a.e \text{ and in }L_{\mathbb{R}}^{1}
$$

Can we say that : $f_\infty=\beta_\infty$ $a.e$?

An idea please.

Answer (score 1):

Yes: as a first remark, notice that for all fixed $k$, $(f_n\mathbf 1\{\lvert f_n\rvert\gt k\})$ converges weakly to $f_\infty-\beta_k$. Moreover, 
$$
\lVert f_\infty-\beta_k\rVert_1\leqslant \liminf_{n\to +\infty}\left\lVert f_n\mathbf 1\{\lvert f_n\rvert\gt k\}\right\rVert_1\leqslant \sup_{n\geqslant 1}\left\lVert f_n\mathbf 1\{\lvert f_n\rvert\gt k\}\right\rVert_1.
$$
Using the fact that [a weakly convergent sequence is uniformly integrable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2705102/weak-convergence-in-l1-implies-uniform-integrability), 
we derive that $\lVert f_\infty-\beta_k\rVert_1\to 0$; since $\beta_k\to \beta_\infty$ in $L^1$, we get the wanted conclusion (and we did not need the almost everywhere convergence).